# Расшифровка переменных типа _0x5518x68

Tags: javascript

В js коде содержаться зашифрованные переменные, в виде

```
var _0x5518x13 = '';
        var _0x5518xf = 0;
        var _0x5518x15 = c1 = c2 = 0;
```

И таких там много. Можно как то, это расшифровать.

Answer (score 1):

Тут нечего расшифровывать в принципе. Код явно обфусцирован, поэтому пути два: 1) искать "чистый" исходник и 2) анализировать исходник самостоятельно и давать переменным свои имена, в соответствии с пониманием кода и логики его работы.

Answer (score 0):

[Шестнадцатеричная система счисления](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) поможет?